# What is generic factory and how to implement it in a factorial program

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

I implemented a simple program in Java to calculate the factorial of a given number in both recursive and iterative methods. I used an interface `Factorial` which is implemented by 2 classes `FactorialRecursive` and `FactorialIterative`. Now I would like to implement a Generic factory which can discover and instantiate possible implementations for any given interface class. Can anyone explain in simple words what is the Generic factory? Is it the same as the generics?

Comment: To me it means a factory that can work with long, integer etc based on type of data provided.

Comment: I think you're looking for [tag:abstract-factory]

Comment: How do you envisage discovery happening? Do you mean like Spring's classpath scanning, where it can find all the things which implement a given interface? Or something more like Java's Service Provider Interface, where libraries explicitly say what services they implement via some meta-information, but the application is then able to discover them all dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `Generic Factory` pattern but the feature to discover all implementations for a specific interface could be realized via the [Service Provider Interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html) feature of Java.